# Prevent an empty submission in React

Tags: reactjs

How would I go about preventing someone from adding nothing my to do list?

***AppTodo.JS***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
export class AddTodo extends Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.addTodo === "") {
      alert("??");
    } else {
      this.props.addTodo(this.state.title);
      this.setState({ title: "" });
    }
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} stlye={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          style={{ flex: "10", padding: "5px" }}
          placeholder="Add Things Todo..."
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
          className="btn"
          style={{ flex: "1" }}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

// Prop Types
AddTodo.propTypes = {
  addTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default AddTodo;
```

I am new to React, just doing it for fun and spent a few hours trying to make conditionals work within the onSumbit method and even in the render() method, but can't seem to make anything work.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have an `addTodo` variable in your state, but you do have a `title` variable.

Change `this.state.addTodo === ""` to `this.state.title === ""` and it will work as expected.

```js
class AddTodo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.title === "") {
      alert("??");
    } else {
      this.props.addTodo(this.state.title);
      this.setState({ title: "" });
    }
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} stlye={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          style={{ flex: "10", padding: "5px" }}
          placeholder="Add Things Todo..."
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
          className="btn"
          style={{ flex: "1" }}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AddTodo addTodo={todo => console.log(`Added todo: ${todo}`)} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This worked +1, however, I would like to understand conceptually as to why, this works in this particular way.

I think I understand it, I was working on this late last night and realized what you said about not having that particular variable. Since, the submission would replace the title: in the array if you set the title = " " ( an empty string), it will check to see if the string is empty and return an error?

Comment: @KingAlmond You had a typo in your code, `addTodo` doesn't exist in your state. When the form is submitted you instead have to check if `title` is the empty string, which is the state variable you use to keep the input value. The submission will only set the `title` back to the empty string if the `title` differs from the empty string.